# How do you sort a list of consts that are either true or false, into two separate arrays, one with the true objects, and one with the false objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

See below:

I have a bunch of const that look like this:

```
 const a = false
 const b = false
 const c = true
 const d = false
 const e = true
 const f = true
```

And I would ultimately like to have two arrays which look like this:

```
 trueArray = [ c, e, f ]
 falseArray = [ a, b, d ]
```

I'm building a filter system in React Native on a map, and I'm getting a value whether a type of place is true (i.e. showing) or false (i.e. not showing), and right now I've made an individual function for each type i.e:

```
bar() {
if (bar === true) {
  return 'bar';
}
return 0;
}
```

And my filter looks like this:

```
 filter={[
            ['!has', 'point_count'],
            ['in', 'type'],
            [
              '!in',
              'type',
              this.activity(),
              this.bar(),
              this.cafe(),
              etc.,
            ]]}
```

Comment: Why not keep those in a single array or object?

Comment: Declaring too much variables like that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: do you have an array of consts at start ?

Comment: You say you want `trueArray = [ c, e, f ]` -- do you mean you want `trueArray = [true, true, true ]` ?

Comment: @MaheerAli same here. And then putting them in two arrays is also meaningless. You'd have an array where all the items are `true` but you don't know which variables those are. It's a very wasteful count of how much of each flag you have.

Comment: @VLAZ I think he want to get the variable names which are `true` or `false`.

Comment: `let numberOfTrues = [a, b, c, d, e, f].filter(b => b).length`; the number of falses is simply `6 - numberOfTrues`. Not sure what you'd do with that information though…

Comment: Well, if you can use ES6, you can just do this: `const [trueArray, falseArray] = [[c,e,f],[a,b,d]];`.

Comment: See edits above for reasoning

Answer (score 2):

There is no way the get the list of variable names declared in a scope.You need to use Objects for that.

You should create an object whose keys will be `a,b...` and values will be `true` or `false`. Then you can `filter()` the keys of the object.

```js
const obj = {
  a:false,
  b:false,
  c:true,
  d:false,
  e:true,
  f:true
}

let truthy = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => obj[x]);
let falsy = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => !obj[x]);

console.log(truthy);
console.log(falsy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using rxjs and its [partition](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html) operator:

```js
const obj = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: true,
  d: false,
  e: true,
  f: true
}

const source = rxjs.from(Object.keys(obj));
let [trueArray, falseArray] = source.pipe(rxjs.operators.partition(key => obj[key]));

(async () => {
  trueArray = await trueArray.pipe(rxjs.operators.combineAll()).toPromise();
  falseArray = await falseArray.pipe(rxjs.operators.combineAll()).toPromise();
  
  console.log('trueArray', trueArray);
  console.log('falseArray', falseArray);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a useless thing to do because all booleans are identical. Instead, you could make a loop to count the number of `true`'s and `false`'s.

```
let trueCount = 0;
let falseCount = 0;
for (let val of myVals) {
    val ? trueCount++ : falseCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using ES6 and beyond, you can put all of your consts in a single array, and then filter it by its true or false objects. The following code implements this idea:

```
const a = false;
const b = false;
const c = true;
const d = false;
const e = true;
const f = true;

let completeArray = [a, b, c, d, e, f];

let trueArray = completeArray .filter(function(object){
    return object;
});

let falseArray = completeArray .filter(function(object){
    return !object;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why ES6 is relevant to the question. You can do that anyway. In fact, if you aren't using ES6, then you won't even have the `const` keyword but you can still do the same thing with `var`.

Comment: While you're using ES6 anyway, do `o => o`/`o => !o` instead of the unwieldy `function` construct.